# Не могу установить nodemon

Tags: node.js, webpack2, node-modules, nodemon

Почему не устанавливается пакет nodemon?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему, подкиньте идею

Comment: попробуй не ставить глобально, а только локально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Запусти cmd через админа
2. Поробуй установить через WebStorm etc.
3. Или установи все пермишены на папку